# How to install angular 9 using NVM

Tags: node.js, angular9, nvm

I have installed Node.js using nvm. How can I install angular9.
Actually i am new to .net core. I am reading a book in which for practice its strongly recommended to install node.js using NVM and using angular9 or above if available.

IF any one can guide about it will be really thankful.

Answer (score 2):

NVM(Node version manager) is a version manager for nodeJs. Angular9 is not dependent on it. You can also do something like install the nodejs(using nvm or direct) in the system and use npm to install the angular and other packages

Use this guide to install the angular
https://angular.io/guide/setup-local

Comment: Thanks for your answer. i have tried to install at explained in above link using but not successful and receiving following warnings "npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported"

Comment: @user7387880 which version of node are you running? use LTS, you can change to lts by 
`nvm use --lts`

Comment: i am using node version 14.17.1

Comment: sachin ananthajumar when using nvm use --lts gives  "node v--lts.0.0 (64-bit) is not installed."

Answer (score 2):

I using nvm as well with new version for angular cli.
try to use angular local as project not a global with -g in your install

You need to have a npx to create a project

To create a project

```
npx -p @angular/cli ng new my-project
```

Enter the path with your project

```
cd my-project
```

To create module, service, component or others use same this

```
npm run ng -g module my-module
```

To start serve

```
npm run ng serve
```

To rum tests

```
npm run ng test
```